# Difference between identifying outliers using LOF and K-means clustering

Tags: outliers, k-means, k-nearest-neighbour, anomaly-detection, localoutlierfactor

I am identifying outliers using K-means and LOF (Local Outlier Factor). Let's say if we are identifying possible outliers using both the techniques, I believe LOF will pick global outliers also as they will also be local to any cluster . LOF distance of outliers identified using K-means will always be high as they will be far away from n neighbors.

Although value of n ( neighbors) will affect LOF outliers but in broader term can I say K-means identified outliers will be subset of LOF outliers??

K-means people know well.Easy article on LOF is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor

My data has multiple operating regions so I am planning to go with LOF but I also believe it should incorporate most of the K-means outliers. Please guide me through this!

Comment: yes to some extent. Number of neighbors would affect performance of LOF. I run both algo on iris data- https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2018/07/anomaly-detection-anomaly-detection-by.html